# Firebase query for the first grandchild of the first child

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Suppose I have the following data structure:

```
parent 
 |- child_1
 |   |- grandchild_1    <-- I want to query this Node
 |   |- ...
 |   `- grandchild_n
 |
 |- ...
 |
 `- child_n
     |- grandchild_1
     |- ...
     `- grandchild_n
```

And I want to query for the first grandchild of the first child. Is this possible using a single Query?

Comment: If it was possible, it'd look pretty unreadable, so I'd recommend splitting the query using different `refs`. Most importantly, have you tried anything? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yeah, I tried splitting but that results in double the boiler plate (listeners)...

Comment: It doesn't even query the first child, so I don't think it is possible...